# JavaScript - Apply if-statement to node-list / multiple elements instead of just one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to see whether an element with an .editable class is clicked on, in that case I want to return false. As you can see in the runnable example, I managed to hard-code a working solution.

However, it works only with the first node in the editableElements list, that is because I do not know how to do the equivalent of $(editableElements).contains(...), i.e. filtering through multiple nodes in an if-statement.

I'd appreciate any help.

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.accordion-item');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(el, i) {
  // onclick handler
  elements[i].onclick = function(e) {
    var editableElements = document.querySelectorAll(".editable");
    // This line works fine with selecting the first element of editableElements node list:
    if (e.target == editableElements[0] || editableElements[0].contains(e.target)) {
    // But I want something more like this, containing all elements:
    // if (e.target == editableElements || editableElements.contains(e.target))
      return false;
    }
    alert("proceeding as usual");
  };
});
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    Click me
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-item">
    Click me
    <div class="editable">Click me and nothing happens 1</div>
    <div class="editable">Click me and nothing happens 2 <i>(not working because node element 1 is hard-coded)</i></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: just like you loop using `foreach` through your `elements` I would expect you can loop using `foreach` through your `editableElements`

Comment: However, an entirely different (and perhaps more conventional) way to achieve your overall goal would be to directly attach a "click" event to elements with the "editable" class and then [stop propagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) of that event so it's doesn't bubble up to the accordion-item.

Comment: that's pretty brilliant!